# I want to limit the Image button animation in specified area

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio

I create an ui in which the image button is animate or moved on touch. But its moving throughout the layout, I want to move it in particular set area.

UPDATE code:

I just clear the animation and use this on behalf. This code lets me to move the Image button on touch in specific radius but it flicker the image means the image is constantly moving around not stopping after touch.

```
 case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                    x = event.getRawX();
                    y = event.getRawY();

                    float deltaX = x - idx;
                    float deltaY = y - idy;
                    double angleInDegrees = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 360 / Math.PI;

                    idx = x;
                    idy = y;

                    imknob.setTranslationX((float)(200*(Math.cos(angleInDegrees))));
                    imknob.setTranslationY((float)(200*(Math.sin(angleInDegrees))));

                    break;
```

Please if someone help me with this !

[image: This is the ui of app]
The red dot image must move inside the black circle. How would I limit it!!

Comment: `setDuration(0)` dont you have a feeling that you are doing something wrong?

Comment: No, it is for animation, when I touch that button it will move on touch response!!

Comment: again, what is the reason of using an animation with duration set to 0?

Comment: It will response fast as I touch the knob!! If it is 0 then it will move fast and if it is any number then it move slow !! if there is no setDuration then it still slow!!

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @pskink I update the code see if u can help me !!